# Error running rails server first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, server

I just started learning rails and I am currently learning through the `Lynda` course **Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training with Kevin Skoglund**. At the point that I have reached, we are trying to build our first web app and we are instructed to create our server by typing `rails server` which as you can see I did. When I type that, that whole loading error mess appears and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\Sites\simple_cms>rails s
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.3/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.3/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `<module:TextHelper>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:29:in `<module:Helpers>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:6:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:18:in `<module:FormTagHelper>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:14:in `<module:Helpers>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:50:in `<module:Helpers>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:7:in `<module:LegacyAssetTagHelper>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:4:in `<module:Sprockets>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `<module:Helper>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:7:in `<module:Rails>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:6:in `<module:Sprockets>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:3:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Bryan/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

 C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\Sites\simple_cms>
```

Comment: Looks like nokogiri isn't available. Did you run `bundle install` prior to starting the server? Not sure what is involved in getting nokogiri to run on windows.

Comment: Thanks for reply Philip, I did run bundle install beforehand and just did it again just to make sure and I still have the same problem. @PhilipHallstrom

Comment: Just for grins, can you try 'bundle exec rails server'?

Comment: I got the same problem again :( @BrianMurphy-Dye

Comment: Drat! Can you verify gem 'nokogiri' is in your Gemfile, and not in a test/development block.

Comment: I'm new to rails so I apologize but can you tell me how to do this please? @BrianMurphy-Dye

Comment: Certainly, not a problem! When you create a rails app, there is will be file called 'Gemfile' in the root of the app. Use your favorite editor to open it up, and add "gem 'nokogiri'" (without the double quotes) if it doesn't already exist. Then run 'bundle' again once you save/exit from the editor.

Comment: Alright I did that and added the gem nokogiri, saved and exited ran 'bundle' and saw that nokogiri was there..then I tried running 'rails server' again and got the same problem @BrianMurphy-Dye

Comment: paste your application.rb file please

Comment: Can tell me how to do that please? @matanco

Comment: i added an answer it should solve your problem.

Comment: Instead of 'rails server', you should always run 'bundle exec rails server'. (There is a way around this, but this is the easy solution.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading "[ask]". Your title doesn't refer to anything in your question, whereas searching SO for `[ruby][ruby-on-rails] "cannot load such file -- nokogiri"` would turn up a number of hits. You tell us a lot that isn't necessary or useful, which doesn't really help. Being concise and direct helps.

Comment: Problem solved thanks so much  @matanco

Comment: My apologies @theTinMan , this is just my second day working with rails so this error occurred I did not even know  how to describe it and did the best I could. However I do appreciate your suggestion and will use it as a model in the future!

Comment: Thanks @BrianMurphy-Dye for being so helpful!

Comment: And last but not least thanks to @PhilipHallstrom for helping too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure your Gemfile contain:

```
gem 'nokogiri'
```

then run `bundle install` command, try run `rails s` if you still get the same error restart your machine to make sure gemset updated.

if the problem still occur edit agian your Gemfile and put:

```
gem 'nokogiri', :require => false
```

run `bundle install` and try run `rails s`.

**edit**

Just noticed you are Windows user and use ruby 2.2 which nokogiri isn't compiled yet for your env, sorry:
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256

Try to downgrade your ruby to 2.0.0.

Comment: Actually that seemed to be only a temporary fix as soon I tried opening the web app on my browser the problem occurred again, I went back in and this time took it further by editing the gem file, running bundle install, and then rails s again which led to the same problem.

Comment: I will look into that thread and see what I can do thanks again!